# Artifactory management for platform components

Tags: design, engineering

What is the recommended approach for managing platform components within our internal JFrog Artifactory? I am currently facing difficulties in defining the appropriate structure.

As an example, we are downloading the open-source Apache NiFi image and storing it locally in our Artifactory using the following URL:
https://platform-docker-release-local.jfrog.url.net/platform-name/apache/nifi:x.0.0

We release updates on a monthly basis, often upgrading NiFi from version x to version y. We have decided to adopt a versioning strategy based on dates (yy.mm). However, the above URL does not incorporate our internal release version. What would be the best way to include our internal release version while also preserving the original component version?
I have considered the following format:
[https://platform-docker-release-local.jfrog.url.net/platform-name/apache/nifi:x.0.0-v[yy].[mm].0](https://platform-docker-release-local.jfrog.url.net/platform-name/apache/nifi:x.0.0-v%5Byy%5D.%5Bmm%5D.0). However, I am uncertain if this is the appropriate approach.

Furthermore, we may have custom images based on the open-source images that we create as part of our CI pipeline. For instance, we have a Spark Kubernetes base image built upon spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2. How should we structure the Artifactory URL to include this information?
I have contemplated using the following format: [https://platform-docker-release-local.jfrog.url.net/platform-name/bespoke/spark-k8s-base-image_[spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2]:nv[yy].[mm].[ci]](https://platform-docker-release-local.jfrog.url.net/platform-name/bespoke/spark-k8s-base-image_%5Bspark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2%5D:nv%5Byy%5D.%5Bmm%5D.%5Bci%5D).

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

The key principle to follow here is to make sure the structure is readable, understandable, and maintainable. The URI structure you've provided seems reasonable, but let's evaluate your proposals in the context of best practices and recommendations.

1. Including the internal release version in the URI

Including the internal version in the URL is definitely a good idea. This makes it clear which version of the application is being used, and the addition of your release version allows you to quickly identify when it was introduced into your environment.

The proposed URL ([https://platform-docker-release-local.jfrog.url.net/platform-name/apache/nifi:x.0.0-v[yy].[mm].0](https://platform-docker-release-local.jfrog.url.net/platform-name/apache/nifi:x.0.0-v%5Byy%5D.%5Bmm%5D.0)) follows a good practice. The format retains the original version number (x.0.0) and appends your internal release version (-v[yy].[mm].0), separated by a hyphen for readability.

2. Incorporating custom images into the URI

For the custom images, it's crucial to be clear about the base image used and the version of the base image. A URL like the one you've suggested ([https://platform-docker-release-local.jfrog.url.net/platform-name/bespoke/spark-k8s-base-image_[spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2]:nv[yy].[mm].[ci]](https://platform-docker-release-local.jfrog.url.net/platform-name/bespoke/spark-k8s-base-image_%5Bspark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2%5D:nv%5Byy%5D.%5Bmm%5D.%5Bci%5D)) does a good job. It's clear what base image is being used and what version it is.

However, it may be even clearer to separate the base image and its version with a dash or some other separator instead of an underscore, as that is more consistent with typical Docker image tagging conventions. For instance:

[https://platform-docker-release-local.jfrog.url.net/platform-name/bespoke/spark-k8s-base-image-[spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2]:nv[yy].[mm].[ci]](https://platform-docker-release-local.jfrog.url.net/platform-name/bespoke/spark-k8s-base-image-%5Bspark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2%5D:nv%5Byy%5D.%5Bmm%5D.%5Bci%5D)

3. Consistent versioning structure

Ensure that your versioning structure is consistent across all your platform components. It should be easy to derive the component version, your release version, and any other versioning or tagging information from the URL alone. This can help reduce confusion and streamline troubleshooting.

In conclusion, your proposed approach seems well thought out. Just remember to keep it consistent, clear, and maintainable. The structure should serve your needs and help you identify and manage components efficiently. It's always a good idea to document your versioning and naming conventions for everyone in your team to follow.